# Not able to remove App pool from IIS

Tags: iis-7

I removed applications from IIS. But still the app pool showing the same apps. Due to this i am not able to delete the app pool.

Is there any other way to delete app pool from IIS?

Thanks,
Prasad

Comment: Have you tried restarting IIS?   iisreset /restart?  If its still there you might have to remove it directly from the metabase...   

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1d1e5de4-fd63-40cd-bc5d-c20521548eed.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

If you removed the applications by deleting their folders, simply add the folders back to the drive with the same paths and names. They can be empty. Then refresh IIS and the applications should show there again. Delete the applications in IIS, then you can delete the folders again. Refresh IIS and they should be gone.